# How to fix An error occurred: (400) Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }' using Google Drive PHP API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Google Drive API in my project. I am stuck at a point regarding refreshing my token.

I am expecting: `An error occurred: (400) Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'` error.

My problem is that it does not let me refresh my token.

Here is complete code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('DBConn.php');

require('google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
require('google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php');
require('google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php');

class ApiMethods extends DBConn
{

    public $CLIENTID = "<somestring>-589hmda0tneueutdo1ouhtuus2qoc0td.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    public $CLIENTSECRET = "<somestring>";
    public $REDIRECTURL = "http://www.<somestring>.com/<somestring>/subscribe.php";
    public $SCOPES = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install');


    public $CLIENTIDTEACHER = "<somestring>-mudd3kfb3bdggjfi19bot0itoaqi6iso.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    public $CLIENTSECRETTEACHER = "<somestring>";
    public $REDIRECTURLTEACHER = "http://www.<somestring>.com/<somestring>/index.php";
    public $DEVELOPERKEYTEACHER = "<somestring>";

    public $DRIVE_SCOPE1 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

    public $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'qwdwe-6gc2cjrlgit1jr3hc0mqlic557kqh5i5@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    public $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'http://www.<somestring>.com/<somestring>/classes/4f9cc06a1081cb5982736079f7c5f25c35aa8c37-privatekey.p12';


    public function buildService($userEmail) {
    $key = file_get_contents($this->SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
    $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $this->SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($this->DRIVE_SCOPE1),
      $key);
     $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setUseObjects(true);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
     return new Google_DriveService($client);
    }

    public function RefreshToken($token) 
    {   
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setClientId($this->CLIENTID);
      $client->setClientSecret($this->CLIENTSECRET);
      $client->setRedirectUri($this->REDIRECTURL);
      $client->setScopes($this->SCOPES);

      $token = json_decode($token);
      try 
      {
        $client->refreshToken($token->refresh_token);
      }
      catch (Exception $e) 
      {
        print "An error occurred: (" . $e->getCode() . ") " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
      }
      $newtoken = $client->getAccessToken();
      return $newtoken;
    } 
}
?>
```

And from that code here is token refresh part:

```
public function RefreshToken($token) 
    {   
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setClientId($this->CLIENTID);
      $client->setClientSecret($this->CLIENTSECRET);
      $client->setRedirectUri($this->REDIRECTURL);
      $client->setScopes($this->SCOPES);

      $token = json_decode($token);
      try 
      {
        $client->refreshToken($token->refresh_token);
      }
      catch (Exception $e) 
      {
        print "An error occurred: (" . $e->getCode() . ") " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
      }
      $newtoken = $client->getAccessToken();
      return $newtoken;
    }
```

And this is code of Google_OAuth2.php:

```
    public function refreshToken($refreshToken) {
    $this->refreshTokenRequest(array(
        'client_id' => $this->clientId,
        'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
        'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
    ));
  }

  private function refreshTokenRequest($params) {
    $http = new Google_HttpRequest(self::OAUTH2_TOKEN_URI, 'POST', array(), $params);
    $request = Google_Client::$io->makeRequest($http);

    $code = $request->getResponseHttpCode();
    $body = $request->getResponseBody();
    if (200 == $code) {
      $token = json_decode($body, true);
      if ($token == null) {
        throw new Google_AuthException("Could not json decode the access token");
      }

      if (! isset($token['access_token']) || ! isset($token['expires_in'])) {
        throw new Google_AuthException("Invalid token format");
      }

      $this->token['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
      $this->token['expires_in'] = $token['expires_in'];
      $this->token['created'] = time();
    } else {
      throw new Google_AuthException("Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '$body'", $code);
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you look through SO, you will say that question asked many times. You should look at the answers and see if any of them (eg. clock drift), are the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have checked all the possible solutions previously. After that I have posted mine here. So please review and code and post the solution if you have. thank you.

Comment: The app is already working in one of my project. Now, I am implementing the app for another project but it failed to do so.

Comment: Of the 5 or so possible causes for "invalid grant", which have you eliminated?

Comment: I have eliminated the Server time one, 2nd wrong Client ID and Client Secret one too. Means these 2 problems are ok and I am pretty sure these are not cause.

Comment: My other apps are working fine but when I try to access the users of my app it show this error. I have a app who registers the users and let them read documents which I shared with them.

Comment: Can you please help me getting through this. thank you please.

Comment: might be worth posting the http request and response into your question. Also generating a new refresh token, in case the current RT is the problem